# AWS AppRunner Breaks When Using Custom Instance Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-app-runner

When launching my container with AppRunner & the default instance role (AWS's built in role), my app immediately fails when it tries to talk to SecretsManager.

This is expected, because the default role doesn't have those permissions.

When I create a custom role with the required permissions though, I see unexpected behavior.

The app instead hangs for almost 5 minutes, before failing with these error messages:

```
11-01-2022 01:45:14 PM npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-01T20_41_26_038Z-debug-0.log
11-01-2022 01:45:14 PM npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
11-01-2022 01:45:14 PM npm ERR! command sh -c -- npx prisma migrate deploy && node ./dist/src/main
11-01-2022 01:45:14 PM npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
11-01-2022 01:45:14 PM npm ERR! command failed
11-01-2022 01:45:14 PM npm ERR! path /
11-01-2022 01:41:32 PM No pending migrations to apply.
```